# newest Xcode 7.1 LaunchScreen.xib warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

After Xcode updated to 7.1 I get a warning which says "This file is set to build for a version older than the project deployment target. Functionality may be limited". I am using launch images source not even using launchScreen.xib

[image: App icons and launch images screen shot]

Comment: Open the XIB file and make sure the "Builds for" setting is set to your min deployment target and/or above

Answer (score 3):

The new way of doing splash screens for iOS 8 onwards is to define a LaunchScreen.xib file. This is also available as a new Resource file type in XCode 6.

This new XIB will use AutoLayout and the new size classes to determine how you want to layout your splash screen.

It is not very clear how the backward compatibility of this will work if you want to support older devices. I figure it will not work.

You can set the launch.xib in the target properties first screen in your XCode project.

If you want to use the old way you can still define splash PNGs to use as launch images, that continues to be fully supported. From what I see, this is still the only way to go if you want to support old iOS versions.

Comment: Does this make it impossible to both support Multitasking enhancements (which need a LaunchScrren.xib, AFAICT) _and_ support devices on iOS7?

Answer (score 0):

open launchScreen.xib file -> Show File Inspector -> in the Interface Builder Document uncheck "Use as Launch Screen"